# How to create a new Snippet in TextMate 2's Bundle Editor?

Tags: textmate

I'm looking at an existing Bundle in TextMate 2's Bundle Editor. **How do I create a new (editable) Snippet in the currently selected Bundle?**

Seems like this should be obvious, but I am stumped. Searching the Main Menu contents doesn't reveal any menu commands which would obviously allow Snippet creation. Right-clicking in various related areas of the UI (in hopes of opening a context menu) has proven fruitless.

Isn't there a way to create a new Snippet inside the TextMate 2 app itself (presumably in the Bundle Editor)? Or do I have to edit plist .tmbundles to create Snippets? I could have sworn you could easily do this in TextMate 1.

[The official TextMate docs](http://manual.macromates.com/en/snippets) seem to be version 1.x-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the bundle editor window, choose File › New (or Cmd + N) and you'll get a sheet like this:

[image]

Just choose 'Snippet' from that drop down.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I can't believe I didn't think to try this.

Comment: Well, it's not like it makes any sense, at all. I remember banging my head against the table for *days* before finally stumbling on this...

Comment: I don't feel so bad about "only" loosing 30 minutes now :).